# Asp.net dynamic dropdownlist access with jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am creating a dynamic `dropdownlist` in asp.net which is under `asp:listview` control code is as below:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lst" OnItemDataBound="lst_dataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="test" ID="ddl"></asp:DropDownList> 
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hf" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />                                           
  <a class="btn btn-success" id='<%#Eval("ID") %>'  onclick="Add('<%#Eval("ID")%>')>Add</a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

on the server side I have given source and bind the list and on item `databound` event I have bound `dropdownlist` which is perfectly but as shown above when I click on an anchor tag I want selected item from drop down for that I have tried this:

```
 var item = $('.test option:selected').text();
         alert(item);
```

which is giving me all list items like if i have 10 list so 10 dropdowns so if each have 4 items take text as(1,2,3,4) 
selected item at each list so randomly it will ("1212134232") which is 10 item in alert but I want single one so I tried another solution I give dynamic cssclass at server side like this

```
DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddl");
HiddenField HF_ID = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hf");
myDDL.ID = "test" + HF_ID.Value;
```

so now I have dynamic class name I can access them at jQuery - JavaScript 
so code which I use them for is

here id is which I will get from function parameter

```
var test = "test" + id;
var item = $('.test option:selected').text();
alert(item);
```

here it should give the right answer but it is not giving it so I try further I inspect element and see if this working and yes its working dynamic css class they have so I have think further and tried like if dynamic side name given like 
test20, test21, etc...
y not try static value so I tried

```
var item = $('.test20 option:selected').text();
    alert(item);
```

and yes its working it is giving me specific dropdown list selected value but this can't be done for statically so I needed help here.

rendered html is:

```
<select class="test29" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_ddl_5" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl5$ddl">
        <option value="85">1</option>
        <option value="86">2</option>
        <option value="87">3</option>
        <option value="88">4</option>

    </select>
```

screen shot of clicking element alert dialog which should give test29(1234(one of them))
but getting....

[image]

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl0$ddl" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_ddl_0" class="test23">
            <option value="65">1</option>
            <option value="66">2</option>
            <option value="67">3</option>
            <option value="68">4</option>

        </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl0$hf" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_hf_0" value="23"> 
                            <a class="btn btn-success" id="23" onclick="Add('23')">
                                Add</a> 
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl1$ddl" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_ddl_1" class="test25">
            <option value="69">1</option>
            <option value="70">2</option>
            <option value="71">3</option>
            <option value="72">4</option>
        </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl1$hf" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_hf_1" value="25"> 
                            <a class="btn btn-success" id="25" onclick="Add('25')">
                                Add </a> 
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl2$ddl" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_ddl_2" class="test26">
            <option value="73">1</option>
            <option value="74">2</option>
            <option value="75">3</option>
            <option value="76">4</option>
        </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl2$hf" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_hf_2" value="26">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" id="26" onclick="Add('26')">
                                Add</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl3$ddl" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_ddl_3" class="test27">
            <option value="77">S</option>
            <option value="78">M</option>
            <option value="79">L</option>
            <option value="80">XL</option>

        </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl3$hf" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_hf_3" value="27">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" id="27" onclick="Add('27')">
                                Add</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl4$ddl" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_ddl_4" class="test28">
            <option value="81">1</option>
            <option value="82">2</option>
            <option value="83">3</option>
            <option value="84">4</option>

        </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lst$ctrl4$hf" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lst_hf_4" value="28">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" id="28" onclick="Add('28')">
                                Add</a>

</div>
```

any other info needed?

Comment: Could you append the rendered HTML outout of anyone item?

Comment: hey updated question needed any more info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code to get the selected value of dropdown in same list item. you need to write it in click event handler so that `this` will give the invoker object and that will help to find the nearest dropdown in same list item.

```
$(this).siblings("select").find(":selected").val()
```

Comment: i want you to give me full html of content within ItemTemplate

Comment: its too long as many drop down list though trying to update question

Comment: @user2800219 do one thing, create jsfiddle of that html and paste it here